# Angular filter data with select menu

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to filter a data table using a select menu. I have both populated and I have a pipe, though I must be doing something wrong, when I select something from the dropdown it just empties the data table generated by the component html.

```html
<div>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectOpt" name="selectOpt" class="password-sort-select" >
<option>Select Team</option>
<option *ngFor="let team of teams" [ngValue]="team.team_id">{{team.team_name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<ul class="company-display-data data-table passwords">
<li *ngFor="let password of passwords | filter: selectOpt" class="cf">
<a class="team-badge-wrapper" href="#"><span class="team-badge">{{password.team_name}}</span></a>
<span class="team-display-data team-description">{{password.description}}</span>
<span class="team-display-data team-url">{{password.url}}</span>
<span class="team-display-data team-username">{{password.username}}</span>
<span class="team-display-data team-password">{{password.password}}</span>
<a class="team-edit" routerLink="/detail/{{password.id}}"><span class="display-data">Edit</span></a>

</li>
</ul>
```

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any, selectOpt?: any): any {
return selectOpt ? items.filter(opt => opt.password_id === selectOpt) : items;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the pipe receiving the correct value for selectOpt ? you could check with a console log in the pipe.

Comment: There isn't anything logging in the console except for the JSON for the three services that are importing the data.

Comment: I see you filter by “password.password_id” field but in your template you mention “password.id” field instead. Do you have both fields on this object or this is just a typo (and therefore the cause of your issue)?

Comment: Hello Anton, that was a typo, but fixing it did not resolve the problem. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipe is returning an empty array when you select a value

```
return selectOpt ? items.filter(opt => opt.password_id === selectOpt) : items;
```

Please match opt.password_id with passwords model

You may also want to fix that it shows nothing when "Select Team" is selected

```
return (selectOpt && selectOpt != 'Select Team') ? items.filter(opt => password_id === selectOpt) : items;
```

working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu

Comment: Never mind the last comment, I got it working, thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a correct way to make the select not be blank until you click on it? I've seen a few solutions but they seem to be hacky.